# how to publish an angular 8 app to the subfolder of asp.net application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config, web-deployment, angular8

I want to publish an angular application in a subfolder. In the main folder, an Asp.Net Mvc web application is running. But I get error.

In the attachments, you can access  Web config structure, Error and folder structure.

[ERROR MESSAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P48E5.png)

[WEB CONFIG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tc8KR.png)

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDVlm.png)

[index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVP0T.png)

Comment: Hi salfenm, welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider adding more information to your question about what you have tried that hasn't worked. The more information you provide, the more likely you are to receive a valuable answer. See this link for help https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: did you use just a simple subfolder? you could try to host an angular site as sub-application or virtual directory [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUjdy.png) wehn you use virtual directory point the dist folder in the physical path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved to add following to web.config.

```html
 <system.webServer>
   <modules>
        <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
    </modules>
 </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience. It will be appreciated if you could mark yourself as answer. So that your post could help more people.